# How to force Series[] to compute expansions by considering non commutative multiplication?

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, series-expansion, algebraic-manipulation, tensors

I wish to compute the Taylor series expansion of the following iteration method $x_{k+1}=x_k-f'(x_k)^{-1}f(x_k)$ up to four terms of error ($e_k=x_k-\alpha$). When this is a scalar iteration, I very simply write the following

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
f[e_] := df*(e^1 + c2 e^2 + c3 e^3 + c4 e^4 + c5 e^5);
fe = f[e];
f1e = f'[e];
Series[f1e^-1, {e, 0, 4}]*df // Simplify
u = e - Series[fe/f1e, {e, 0, 4}] // Simplify
```

and obtain correct results
$$f(x_k)^{-1}=[1-2 \text{c2} e_k+ \left(4 \text{c2}^2-3 \text{c3}\right)e_k^2$$
$$-4 (2 c2^3 - 3 c2 c3 + c4) e_k^3 + (16 c2^4 - 36 c2^2 c3 + 9 c3^2 + 
16 c2 c4 - 5 c5) e_k^4]f'({\alpha})^{-1}.$$
But, how to do this for the multi-dimensional case. That is, when the coefficients $c2,c3,c4$, and even $df=f'({\alpha})^{-1}$ are all matrices (note that e.g. $c2=\frac{1}{2!}f'(\alpha)^{-1}f^{(2)}(\alpha)$). By hand, I obtain the following correct results:
$$
f(x_k)^{-1}=\left(I-2c2e_k+(4c2^2-3c3)e_k^2+(6c3c2+6c2c3-8c2^3-4c4)e_k^3\\ 
+ (8c4c2+9c3^2+8c2c4-5c5-12c3c2^2-12c2c3c2-12c2^2c3+16c2^4)e_k^4\right)f'(\alpha)^{-1}
$$
and
\begin{equation}
e_{k+1}=x_{k+1}-\alpha=-c2e_k^2+(2c2^2-2c3)e_k^3+(-4c2^3+4c2c3+3c3c2-3c4)e_k^4+\mathcal{O}(e_k^5).
\end{equation}

So, my question is how to handle this non-commutative multiplication inside `Series[]` (e.g. $c2c3$ is not equal to $c3c2$ in this case)? I also tried to apply $**$, but I failed. Any suggestions or tricks to solve this problem will be appreciated fully.

I also saw the following posts in MathematicaStackExchange, but they were not useful for this problem, [How to make noncommutative multiplication agree with commutative multiplication](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44157/how-to-make-noncommutative-multiplication-agree-with-commutative-multiplication) and [Noncommutative multiply- expand expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23076/non-commutative-multiply-expand-expression).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One idea is to use the function [MatrixD](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162063/45431) from my answer to question [det simplification](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/161918/45431) that takes scalar derivatives of functions of matrices:

```
MatrixD[expr_, x__] := With[
    {old = OptionValue[SystemOptions[], "DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions"]},

    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
        SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions"->Join[old, {Det, Inverse, Tr}]];

        Unprotect[D];
        (* handle list derivatives *)
        D[h:((Det|Tr|Inverse)[m_]), {z_, n_Integer}] := Nest[D[#, Replace[z, _List :> {z}]]&, h, n];
        D[h:((Det|Tr|Inverse)[m_]), {z_List}] := D[h, #]& /@ z;
        D[h:((Det|Tr|Inverse)[m_]), z_, y___] := D[D[h, z], y];

        (* define derivatives for Det, Tr, and Inverse *)
        D[Det[m_], z:Except[_List]] := Det[m] Tr[Inverse[m] . D[m,z]];
        D[Tr[m_], z:Except[_List]] := Tr[D[m,z]];
        D[Inverse[m_], z:Except[_List]] := -Inverse[m] . D[m, z] . Inverse[m],

        D[expr, x],

        SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions"->old];
        Clear[D];
        Protect[D]
    ]
]
```

Here are your expressions:

```
f[e_] := df*(IdentityMatrix[d] e^1 + c2 e^2 + c3 e^3 + c4 e^4 + c5 e^5);
fe = f[e];
f1e = f'[e];
```

I added the [`IdentityMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IdentityMatrix) and assumed that `df` is just a scalar. Then:

```
MatrixD[Inverse[f1e], e] /. e->0
```

> -Inverse[df IdentityMatrix[d]].(2 c2 df).Inverse[df IdentityMatrix[d]]

In order to make progress, we need to include assumptions about the coefficients:

```
$Assumptions = (c2 | c3 | c4 | c5) ∈ Matrices[{d, d}] && df ∈ Complexes;
```

The first few derivatives of `Inverse[f1e]` tensor expanded using the above assumptions:

```
TensorExpand[MatrixD[df Inverse[f1e], e] /. e->0]
TensorExpand[MatrixD[df Inverse[f1e], e, e] /. e->0]
TensorExpand[MatrixD[df Inverse[f1e], e, e, e] /. e->0]
```

> -2 c2
>
> -6 c3 + 8 MatrixPower[c2, 2]
>
> -24 c4 + 36 c2.c3 + 36 c3.c2 - 48 MatrixPower[c2, 3]

So, the series expansion is:

```
TensorExpand[
    (df Inverse[f1e] /. e->0) +
    (MatrixD[df Inverse[f1e], e] /. e->0) e +
    (MatrixD[df Inverse[f1e], e, e] /. e->0) e^2/2! + 
    (MatrixD[df Inverse[f1e], e, e, e] /. e->0) e^3/3! +
    (MatrixD[df Inverse[f1e], e, e, e, e] /. e->0) e^4/4!
] + O[e]^5 //TeXForm
```

> $\operatorname{IdentityMatrix}[d]-2 \operatorname{c2} e+e^2 (4
>    \operatorname{MatrixPower}[\operatorname{c2},2]-3 \operatorname{c3})+e^3 (-8
>    \operatorname{MatrixPower}[\operatorname{c2},3]+6
>    \operatorname{c2}.\operatorname{c3}+6 \operatorname{c3}.\operatorname{c2}-4
>    \operatorname{c4})+e^4 (-12
>    \operatorname{c3}.\operatorname{MatrixPower}[\operatorname{c2},2]-12
>    \operatorname{MatrixPower}[\operatorname{c2},2].\operatorname{c3}+16
>    \operatorname{MatrixPower}[\operatorname{c2},4]+9
>    \operatorname{MatrixPower}[\operatorname{c3},2]-12
>    \operatorname{c2}.\operatorname{c3}.\operatorname{c2}+8
>    \operatorname{c2}.\operatorname{c4}+8 \operatorname{c4}.\operatorname{c2}-5
>    \operatorname{c5})+O\left(e^5\right)$

which is in basic agreement with your inverse computation. A similar computation can be done for `Inverse[f1e] . fe`. However, I will instead present an approach teaching [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) to use `MatrixD` for matrix functions. The internal function used by [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) is `` System`Private`InternalSeries ``, so we teach this internal function about [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) and [`Inverse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inverse):

```
Unprotect[System`Private`InternalSeries];
System`Private`InternalSeries[a_Inverse|a_Dot, {e_,e0_,n_}] := SeriesData[
    e,
    e0,
    TensorReduce[TensorExpand[NestList[MatrixD[#,e]&,a,n]/.e->e0]]/Range[0,n]!,
    0,
    n+1,
    1
]
```

Now, we can use [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) directly:

```
Series[df Inverse[f1e], {e, 0, 4}] //TeXForm
```

> $\operatorname{IdentityMatrix}[d]-2 \operatorname{c2} e+e^2 (4
>    \operatorname{MatrixPower}[\operatorname{c2},2]-3 \operatorname{c3})+e^3 (-8
>    \operatorname{MatrixPower}[\operatorname{c2},3]+6
>    \operatorname{c2}.\operatorname{c3}+6 \operatorname{c3}.\operatorname{c2}-4
>    \operatorname{c4})+e^4 (-12
>    \operatorname{c3}.\operatorname{MatrixPower}[\operatorname{c2},2]-12
>    \operatorname{MatrixPower}[\operatorname{c2},2].\operatorname{c3}+16
>    \operatorname{MatrixPower}[\operatorname{c2},4]+9
>    \operatorname{MatrixPower}[\operatorname{c3},2]-12
>    \operatorname{c2}.\operatorname{c3}.\operatorname{c2}+8
>    \operatorname{c2}.\operatorname{c4}+8 \operatorname{c4}.\operatorname{c2}-5
>    \operatorname{c5})+O\left(e^5\right)$

in agreement with the previous result. Finally:

```
Series[Inverse[f1e] . fe, {e, 0, 4}] - e IdentityMatrix[d] //TeXForm
```

> $-\operatorname{c2} e^2-2 e^3
>    (\operatorname{c3}-\operatorname{MatrixPower}[\operatorname{c2},2])+e^4 (-4
>    \operatorname{MatrixPower}[\operatorname{c2},3]+4
>    \operatorname{c2}.\operatorname{c3}+3 \operatorname{c3}.\operatorname{c2}-3
>    \operatorname{c4})+O\left(e^5\right)$

in agreement with your result.

Comment: Wow, a very useful response. The step-by-step way to get the multi-dimensional Taylor expansion is fruitful.

Answer (score 2):

This can be calculated by using [NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC) and [this answer another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110658). The function

```
NCSeries[f_, {x_, x0_, n_}] := Block[{h}, 
SetNonCommutative[h]; 
Plus @@ (Table[1/i!, {i, 0, n}]*NestList[NCDirectionalD[#, {x, h}] &, f, n]) /. x -> x0 /. h -> x]
```

will calculate a formal power series of rational noncommutative functions. Your example is mixed, in the sense that `e` seems to commute but the coefficients do not. I propose that you *lift* `e` into a noncommutative variable `ee`

```
SNC[c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, ee] 
f[e_] := df*(e^1 + c2 ** e^2 + c3 ** e^3 + c4 ** e^4 + c5 ** e^5);
fe = f[ee]
f1e = f'[ee]   (* this works as expected in this simple case only! *)
```

use `NCSeries` to calculate the formal power series

```
series = NCSeries[ee - inv[f1e] ** fe, {ee, 0, 4}]
```

which you can then project back by replacing `ee` by the commutative `e`:

```
SetCommutative[e];
Collect[NCExpand[series /. ee -> e], e]
```

which will give the result you're looking for.